# qt : How can I make QGraphicsItem not selected in specific situation?

Tags: qt, selection, qgraphicsitem

It seems a little bit silly, as I write above I want to QGraphicsItem not be selected in some ways.
I imagine a item that act separately in keyboard modifier. If I click the item with *NO-modifier*, it just is selected. If I click the item with *ALT-modifier* and drag, it moves along the mouse move. At that time, I want not to change the selection state of the item. In **mousePressEvent**, i try to set the **event.ignore()** but it ruins the item. How can I access to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 simple solutions.

Version 1)
In `mousePressEvent`, check the flags of your item, and store the selection state. On `mouseReleaseEvent`, restore the saved state

Version 2)
Subclass `QGraphicsItem` and store the state of the event as a private flag.